# SSRS Error after Changing User

Tags: reporting-services

The "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)" was running as "NT Service\ReportServer".

I changed the account to a domain account with local admin rights so it could have access to some LAN resources.

Now I get "The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content."

How do I restore the service as "NT Service\ReportServer" so that I can backup this key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Set the Reporting Service to run as "NT Service\Report Server" and set the password to be blank and this should fix everything.

To switch the Reporting Service user correctly you must first do this...
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842421